# Variable from different file in function without using global

Tags: php, procedural

Ay,

I defined (in config.php):

```
$mysql = mysqli_connect (..);
```

for connecting to the mySQL database.
now I want to use the variable in my functions (functions.php):

```
function x () { $fetch = ($mysql, "SELECT ...")); }
```

without using global:

```
function x () { global $mysql ... }
```

any clean ideas (procedural)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can e.g. pass the connection resource to your function

```
function x ($mysqli) { $mysqli->... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access variables in global-scope without the global-keyword by using the Superglobal $GLOBALS:

```
function x() { $GLOBALS['mysql']->... }
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

I would recommend to create a separate function that returns the Database-Handle/Object you can use instead of the variable. e.g.:

```
function db() { return $GLOBALS['mysql']; }
function x() { db()->... }
```